# How would I test my matrix class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am currently working in my matrix class. After completion of the matrix I am planing to write a unit test for this matrix class testing all the functions that I wrote.

```
class Matrix{
    Matrix(size_t, size_t);
    Matrix transpose();
    Matrix operator+(const Matrix&)const;
    ...

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
};
```

How am I planning to test?

Well currently I am planning not use any external library and use my own testing method.

```
void test_transpose(){
    matrix a = {...some value..}; // nxm

    // I calculate the expected value via matlab
    matrix expected = {...some value..}; // mxn
    matrix b = a.transpose();

    assert(expected == b);
}

void test_xxxxx1(){

    ....
} 

int main(){

    test_transpose();  
    test_xxxxx1();
    test_xxxxx2();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone give me advice if the method I am following is correct or is there any better method that I should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I know you said that you're not planning on using an external library, but this is what I've done in similar situations with great success:

1) Generate millions of random matrix math problems and save them in a file. Make sure you cover every edge case you can think of while generating matrices.

2) Get the answers using Matlab or Octave and save them in another file.

3) Test that your code by reading both files and checking that you get the same answers.

You're not so much using an external library in your code as you are creating a set of test cases with answers to check your code against.

Comment: To generate millions of random matrix : how do you do this? do you use random number generator? and use this random number to create matrix of random sizes (nxm) and use random number again to create entries for those random matrix that we just created?

Comment: Further more my test class should also have functionality to read file right? Reading the file for reading the millions of random matrix we had created in step 1 and saved in file and also read file to read the answers created from Matlab.

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that matrices with random entries will almost surely be full-rank. For certain operations, e.g. Gaussian elimination, you'll want to have test cases using singular matrices as well.

Comment: @pokche Your class definitely shouldn't have a functionality to read a file.  It's a separate concern from martix calculation and should be handled by a separate class.

Comment: @Eternal21 oh ok! so in that case .. create a instance of the class that has functionality to read a file inside test class and go from there?

Comment: @pokche That would be one way of doing it.  Or you can have your Matrix class accept an IDataSource interface object that exposes 'GetData()' function.  In your test you'd implement that interface using a file reader.  In your production code you'd implement it by reading data from memory.  Look up constructor dependency injection.  You can implement interfaces using pure virtual classes in c++.

Comment: @Eternal21 , he didn't ask whether his matrix class could read a file, but rather whether his test class would need to be able to write a file. It is true that the best way for a test class to read input such as that would be to accept a stream as input, but you need to be careful not to go down the road of building castles in the sky.

Comment: @riwalk You're right. I understood his comment to ask about his class under test to be able to read the file, which would clearly be wrong.

Comment: @riwalk What does Matlab or Octave do to test the correctness of their matrix multiplication? I'd be interested to hear how you would answer the same question prior to the production of Matlab and similar platforms/tools.

Answer (score 1):

It will be depend a little on what matrix functions you are planning to implement, so a few tests that I would suggest:

- Transpose - could be done in O(1) time.
- Multiplications - overflows  are easy, check with large numbers.
- Inversion – mix in a few 0 and watch Gaussian elimination go very wrong.

Some matrices are much harder to work with numerically, but have analytical solution or special case numerical solutions. Vandermonde matrix is something I had lots of fun with. Or just try to invert a tridiagonal matrix where each next row is 10 times the previous row. That should have very high condition ratio.

Also checking some basic matrix identities like A(B + C) = AB + AC.